# Does google-cloud-vision stores uploaded images ? what is privacy policy for that?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I want to implement google-cloud-vision API for OCR on my Project.
But due to compliance issues, I need to know does google-cloud-vision stores the uploaded image? if yes what is the privacy policy for that?

Does anyone have any information regarding this?

Thanks!

Comment: is there a way to access the stored images you sent to the service?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they do need to store the uploaded image in order to process it. You can refer to the section 1.3 and 1.4 of the following document. https://cloud.google.com/terms/

Answer (score 2):

You can find out what you need to know here.

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage

Answer (score 1):

**This can provide you some info straight to the point**

Google says:

When you send an image to Vision API, we must store that image for a short period of time in order to perform the analysis and return the results to you. For asynchronous offline batch operations, **the stored image is typically deleted right after the processing is done**, with a failsafe Time to live (TTL) of a few hours. For online (immediate response) operations, the image data is processed in memory and not persisted to disk

Get more info on [Google Vision FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage) about this question